# How to implement caching in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to implement cache functionality in spring jpa repository using Ehcache with java configuration(not by xml). But am confused about the @cache, @caceevict,@cacheable, @caching annotations.

1) I want to have data from cache, if data not available in cache then it should be fetch from database.

2) from controller if I hit /api/cacheRefresh, it should refresh all the tables.

Comment: Have you gone through the spring docs thoroughly, they are very clear on each type of annotation for caching

Comment: JPA uses it's own caching. I doubt that adding a cache on top of that is doing anything good.

Answer (score 1):

In a typical application you would have layers like:

- **repositories**, which have access to your "storages", for example db, nosql, etc, as well as data coming from external services through for example rest calls
- **services**, which may or may not contain the business logic and use repositories to collect all the data needed to apply that business logic

You usually don't put caches on the repositories layer, but instead this should be done on the services layer. So to answer to your question, you should let the JPA repositories as clean as you can, and put `@Cacheable`/`@CacheEvict` annotations on the service that accesses the repository, for example:

```
public class MyService {

    private final MyRepository repository;

    public MyService(MyRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Cacheable
    public MyItem findOne(Long id) {
        return repository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Cacheable
    public List<MyItem> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @CacheEvict
    public void evict() {

    }

}
```

Eventually from your controller you can call the `evict` method of the `MyService` class when you need to refresh the cache and still benefit from the cache when you call `findOne`/`findAll` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Fabio said, you can configure the cache limits in ehcache.xml ( put this in classpath).

```
<cache name="gendersCache" 
      maxEntriesLocalHeap="400"
      maxEntriesLocalDisk="600" 
      eternal="false" 
      diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20" 
      timeToIdleSeconds="1800" 
      timeToLiveSeconds="3600" 
      memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" 
      transactionalMode="off">
      <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </cache>
```

For Springboot add below line in application.properties

```
 spring.cache.ehcache.config=classpath:ehcache.xml
```

For regular spring application, add below line your applicationContext.xml file

```
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:config-location="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml" p:shared="true"/>
```